# d3.js water bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am trying to fix this watery bar chart so that it can handle dynamic data sets -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1855/

Having an issue with the positioning of the labels and adjusting the width/height of the lines.

```
    var lineHeights = 100;

    //__ labels
    var labels = labelsholder.selectAll("text")
      .data(data);

    labels.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "barlabels")
      .attr("x", 200)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return lineHeights - (20 * i);
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      })

    var lines = lineholder.selectAll("line")
      .data(data);

//horizontal


    lines.enter()
      .append("line") // attach a line
      .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
      .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
      .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
        return barWidth - 100/(i+1);
      }) //x pos of the 1st end of the line
      .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
        return lineHeights - (20 * i);
      }) //y pos of the 1st end of the line
      .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
        return barWidth;
      }) //x pos of the 2nd end of the line
      .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
        return lineHeights - (20 * i);
      }); //y pos of the 2nd end of the line



//verticals

    lines.enter()
      .append("line") // attach a line
      .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
      .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
      .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      }) //x pos of the 1st end of the line
      .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
        return lineHeights - (20 * i);
      }) //y pos of the 1st end of the line
      .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      }) //x pos of the 2nd end of the line
      .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
        return -15;
      }); //y pos of the 2nd end of the line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1860/

Where you were appending the horizontal lines, you were using `barWidth - 100/(i+1);` to determine the x-axis. This would have worked if `barWidth` was actually the width of each bar, (but it had been set to 150 instead?)

```
     .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 30);
```

Each bar has a width of `20` and a margin of `5` on each side. So to calculate the offset, just multipy the bar number, `i` by with total width of the bar, `30`.

Comment: This looks good - I've removed the comment on reversing data -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1861/  -- is there any other improvements that can be made on this chart?

Comment: What do you mean by other improvements? (Code can nearly always be improved).

Comment: I mean do you see any enhancements to this code base - making the code tighter - @Lissy

Comment: Yes! There's always enchantments you can make, this code could looks okay - just needs a bit of a refactor. But StackOverflow is not for getting people to refactor your code ;)